# Cross-framework project with .net core 5 and .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#

I need to create a cross-framework project (.NET 5 + full .NET framework 4.7.2). Can you please let me know how to do this? As I know .NET Standard library is already included in .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a library project, you could *either* use a netstandard target (in the project csproj):

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

or multi-target:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net472;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

The latter has the advantage of allowing you to use newer features *when available*, by using things like:

```cs
#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER
 // up-level version
#else
 // down-level version
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Write all the code you want to share as .NET Standard library. Then use this library in projects that target specific framework. .NET Standard isn't "included" in .Net Core, it's rather a target that allows you to share code between core and framework